# how to know the sql join size taken by the query?

Tags: mysql

knowing the join size or combinationns taken by the query can help me to optimize the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever query are you using add EXPLAIN at the beginning, for example:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id < 1000
```

and look for estimated number of rows that mysql would need to check.